# Python type of generic Enum class of str

Tags: python, enums, python-typing

Is there a generic `type` of enum that is possible for the following function `format_enum_as_list_with_quotes`:

```py
from enum import Enum, EnumMeta


class Demo(str, Enum):
    one = "one"
    two = "two"
    three = "three"


def format_enum_as_list_with_quotes (items: EnumMeta) -> str:
    return ", ".join([f"\"{item.value}\"" for item in items])
#                               ^^^^^ Cannot access member "value" for type "EnumMeta"
#                                     Member "value" is unknown


def format_enum_as_list_with_quotes_2 (items: Enum) -> str:
    return ", ".join([f"\"{item.value}\"" for item in items])
#                                                     ^^^^^ "Enum" is not iterable
#                                                           "__iter__" method not defined


print(type(Demo))  # => EnumMeta
assert format_enum_as_list_with_quotes(Demo) == '"one", "two", "three"'
```

* edit *

The code executes fine I just want to get rid of the type errors.

Type errors show from pylance v2024.2.2 in Visual Studio Code with Python 3.10.11

Comment: Are you asking to solve the errors in the comments? because I don't get them.

Comment: I don't get those *exact* errors with 1.8.0, but there are similar errors. What are you using for type checking? (And it is the type checker that has the problem; the code itself executes as expected.)

Comment: This should pass with `type[Enum]` hint instead of `EnumMeta`: enums are magic, they are special-cased in type checkers. `EnumMeta` should work also, but may be just not supported.

Comment: https://pyright-play.net/?code=GYJw9gtgBApgdgV2gSwgBzCALlAooiAGjwIFkYsBDAWACg66BjAG0oGc2oARGCMACjZYQxfEgCUALjpRZUMHBhQAvFABECmGplysAdzAr1%2BsNtpyoWABYgYS1Wuu2tDerQAmMYFGCYIlLAB9eCRA9kDmZCFAvWRrQIBHBDAsGE5%2BON42SUsATzQYAG0xCABdcSgAWgA%2BKCEQaXM5WywEEDh1YjUAOgArMGQ4fkLgNQAdNQBvTIhugDdKZgQYAF8JtR9MKBntjpm2ctc6T29fEH8gkIgwtgiooNj4pJS0wIAmKAzUiGySJHIqBUanVhI0LC02h01F0%2BgMhiNxlMZvNFss1moNmdtt9dtisoc3GgQIMsPwsPkYPweHxxBUoABiFS1EoAmi0dhsGDYTbnALBAg3O7RR5WRLJVJsKm8MAVZSqADkGkU0OMBhVjhsdjU8roQA

Comment: Thanks @STerliakov , could you post as an answer please and I'll accept it. I had a look (I asked GitHub's copilot) and it appears that we "should" use `from typing import Type` and `Type[Enum]` instead? ... though the type errors from pylance disappear with either `type[Enum]` or `Type[Enum]`.

Comment: `typing.Type` is an old (pre-3.9) way when `type` was not subscriptable.

Comment: Great thanks.  Can you post your comment as an answer now please @STerliakov ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Enum`s are very special language constructs, and so are special-cased in typecheckers. While you're correct that `type(Demo)` is `EnumMeta` (that's how real implementation works - enums have a special metaclass), typecheckers are not good enough to interpret it the same way as `type[Enum]`. The latter should provide a solution to your problem:

```py
def format_enum_as_list_with_quotes(items: type[Enum]) -> str:
    return ", ".join(f"\"{item.value}\"" for item in items)
```

(on python 3.8 and below use `typing.Type` instead of `type`). Note that I removed brackets above - there's no need to construct a list, just join a generator directly.

This passes both mypy ([playground](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.11&flags=strict&gist=55d2f38e5974c29e441ecbcb03fe5009)) and pyright ([here](https://pyright-play.net/?code=GYJw9gtgBApgdgV2gSwgBzCALlAooiAGjwIFkYsBDAWACg66BjAG0oGc2oARGCMACjZYQxfEgCUALjpRZUMHBhQAvFABECmGplysAdzAr1%2BsNtpyoWABYgYS1Wuu2tDerQAmMYFGCYIlLAB9eCRA9kDmZCFAvWRrQIBHBDAsGE5%2BON42SUsATzQYAG0xCABdcSgAWgA%2BKCEQaXM5WywEEDh1YjUAOgArMGQ4fkLgNQAdNQBvTIhugDdKZgQYAF8JtR9MKBntjpm2ctc0EEGsfix8mH4ePnEKqABiFVqS8io6djYYbE2QfyCQhAwmwIlEgrF4kkUmlrrwwBVlKoAOQaRRqLomdHGGx2NRIuhAA)).